# MSSQL Join Calendar table with results table

Tags: sql-server

I'm asking for your kindly explanation on this.

I have a Calendar table, where each day is having a row. Also I have a table with backup results, where the date and time of backup start is stored.

My goal is to have this result:

```
date of month | serverid | datetime of backup | result | note (not in table, for info only)
2022-02-02    |       11 | 2022-02-02 19:00   | OK     | backup was successful
2022-02-03    |     NULL | NULL               | NULL   | backup was not even start
2022-02-04    |       11 | 2022-02-04 19:00   | FAILED | backup started but error occured
```

I tried LEFT OUTER JOIN and OUTER APPLY.
LEFT OUTER JOIN is not returning the null lines where backup is not started
OUTER APPLY is working much better, but when I filter results by Year, Month (from calendar table) and serverid, NULL lines are gone also.

So my goal is to select ALL lines from calendar table in the specified month and year and assign the results to them by the backup start datetime column to see the days where the backup was not started also.

Can you please point me at right way?

Best Regards, Jan

Example of queries:

```
SELECT        [SqlDt], [Year], [Month], A.*
FROM            [portal].[dbo].[Calendar] C OUTER APPLY
                             (SELECT        *
                               FROM            [DS-Backup] D
                               WHERE        [C].[SqlDt] = CAST(D .VersionDate AS Date)) A


SELECT        dbo.Calendar.SqlDt, dbo.Calendar.Year, dbo.Calendar.Month, dbo.[DS-Backup].EID, dbo.[DS-Backup].VersionDate, dbo.[DS-Backup].VersionStatus
FROM            dbo.Calendar LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         dbo.[DS-Backup] ON dbo.Calendar.SqlDt = CAST(dbo.[DS-Backup].VersionDate AS Date)
```

Comment: You forgot to post the query. Basically you select everything from the calendar table and left join it to whatever else. Remember that if serverid is NULL and you filter on it, it will exclude the row. Is every server meant to have a backup every day? to represent this you need to first cross join the calendar table with the server table to represent that. Then left join to the actual activity

Comment: I add the queries.  So I need to filter results of backups before I can join it to the calendar?

Comment: As posted, both queries should do exactly what you want. Since you say they do not, then there must be some other issue with the data or the actual code you are using. I'll point out that your queries do NOT produce the resultset you claim. It is odd and highly suspicious that your code mixes 2 and 3 part names generally. It is also a bad habit NOT to define an alias for every table and NOT use that alias for every column reference.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for useful commnets, I was not filter the table with backup results before join.

Now it is working the way I want:

```
    SELECT [SqlDt],[Year],[Month],[Backups].*
  FROM [portal].[dbo].[Calendar] 
  LEFT JOIN ( SELECT * FROM [portal].[dbo].[DS-WindowsServerBackup] WHERE EID=11) as Backups
  ON Calendar.SqlDt = CAST([Backups].[VersionDate] as Date)
```